# Cannot enter bios on a Lenovo G505

Tags: bios, lenovo-laptop

I've a Lenovo g505 laptop. the HD failed and I've installed a new HD. All I get now is a white static cursor on the top let hand corner of the screen.

[image]

The screen just lights up and has no colour. I've tried all the key combinations and also disconnecting the battery and mains then holding the power button for 20 seconds.
The old drive is totally dead so I cannot re-install it to get to the recovery partition.

Does anyone know how to either re-install the bios or how to get into the bios so that I can enable legacy options?

Comment: You sure it was the hard drive that failed?

Comment: Yes, I tried it in an external drive caddy and the drive was not recognised. Could not see it or format it

Comment: With older laptops and PC's we could download the bios onto a floppy then boot from the floppy and re-install the bios. Is there a way of reinstalling the bios but baring in mind I'm not given the option to choose a boot device when I press F12 or any combination I can think of to get me in to the boot option screen.

Answer (score 1):

**Every Lenovo notebook has a small button (usually beside of the Power-Off-Botton)**

[image]

**After pressing this small button (without pressing other keys) you should enter to this ...**

[image]

**Then select the "BIOS-SETUP" to enter to the bios!**

> Very important: The notebook has to be off, when you want to enter it to the bios. Also, when you going to press the "Small Button" do not press any other key at the same time. And don't touch the Power-Off-Button!

Comment: Thanks for that but I've tried that too. All I get is a white cursor on the top right hand corner of the screen and no colour or logo or any options at all.

Comment: @Chris Could you make a photo of that?

Comment: From what I can understand these laptops have been configured to boot using UEFI which speeds up shut down and start up in Windows 8. If I could get into the bios and turn off the UEFI option the I can install any operating system, I like but it's getting into the bios that's proving the problem.

Comment: I'm new to this site so trying to figure out how to insert a photo

Comment: Post just the links of your pictures in the question!

Comment: I've put a link on the original question. All you can see is the screen is lit up and the cursor

Comment: @Chris  UEFI isn't that relevant.  Maybe he needs to figure out how to shut his computer down properly from windows, so that when he turns it on it boots up.  Maybe he should look at restarting.